# What is the SWT equivalent of MouseMotionListener that's in AWT?

Tags: java, awt, swt, mouselistener

I am converting a project over from AWT to SWT. The original project uses the `MouseDragged()` method in the MouseMoitionListener class. I've noticed the MouseListener class in SWT only has `MouseDown(), MouseUp()` and `MouseDoubleClick().`Is there an SWT motion listener? If not does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `MouseMoveListener` which gives you the movement events.

You will probably also need to use `MouseListener` to get the mouse button up / down events.

Alternatively you can use the lower level `addListener` method for the `SWT.MouseMove`, `SWT.MouseDown` and `SWT.MouseUp` events.